# How to do a recursive LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, recursion

I have a recursive data structure, such as linked list:

```
class Node
{
    private Node next;
    private int data;

    // (...)
    public Node Next
    {
        get
        {
            return next;
        }
    }

    public int Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to make a LINQ query, which starts from the head of the list and then goes through the elements, collecting data on the fly. How to do that?

Comment: Do you have a `List<Node>` on which you want to apply `LINQ`, or you just have a `Node` instance which hierarchically have more instances of `Node` class and you want to get data from all objects sequentially from head to tail?

Comment: A single `Node` only. If I had `List<Node>`, I could simply use existing `LINQ` extensions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to traverse arbitrary complex data-structures with just simple LINQ queries. At some point, you'll have to 'cut your losses' and write iterator blocks yourself - possibly only for the parts that are hard to express with standard LINQ.

That said, for your linked list example, with [moreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), you can do:

```
MoreEnumerable.Generate(head, node => node.Next)
              .TakeWhile(node => node != null)
```

If you want recursive LINQ  tree traversal (or similar), it would be quite different, but here's a sample (depth-first):

```
private static IEnumerable<Node> GetNodeAndDescendants(Node node)
{
   return new[] { node }.Concat(node.Children.SelectMany(GetNodeAndDescendants));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two helper classes I us to parse all the nodes in a TreeView control.

You might be inspired by how the `yield` keyword is used to adapt it for your needs.

```
internal static IEnumerable<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeNodeCollection c)
{
    foreach (var node in c.OfType<TreeNode>())
    {
        yield return node;

        foreach (var child in node.Nodes.Descendants())
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

```
var allCheckedNodes = myTreeView.Nodes.Descendants().Where(c => c.Checked);
```

Comment: This is one cool solution, though it is created for specific class, and I like the generic+lambda one more, because it is a little bit more flexible. A giant +1 for `yield` though - it simplified my code a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Mostly probably it is not possible using regular LINQ extensions, but one can use the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<U> For<T, U>(this T obj, Func<T, U> extract, Func<T, bool> continueCondition, Func<T, T> step)
{
    while (!continueCondition(obj))
    {
        yield return extract(obj);
        obj = step(obj);
    }
}
```

And from now on, you can write cool queries, like:

```
head.For(n => n.SomeData, n => n != null, n => n.Next)
    .Select(n => n.Data)
    // More LINQ here
```

For instance, let's sum up all even numbers from 1 to 20 (in the fancy linq-maniac way)

```
int sum = 1.For(n => n, n => n <= 20, n => n + 1)
    .Where(n => n % 2 == 0)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: This looks like a more complex version of MoreLINQ's `Generate`. There's really no need for `continueCondition` since LINQ has `TakeWhile`, or for `extract` since LINQ has `Select`

Comment: @BenAaronson Well, with the exception, that you have to remember about `TakeWhile` every time you use it (I agree though with no need for `extract`). And since generally that's the most common scenario, I'd vote on keeping this one :)

Comment: Yeah, it generally makes sense to have